# Building a cross browser compatible jquery mobile event calender ( not date picker ) ? who has done it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, calendar

There are several good event calenders out there but the problem is compatibility. 
Is there one documented to be compatible over all browsers , ios, android etc?

I found no references to any event calender for jquery mobile so far. 
Who knows one that is compatible and can be integrated in jquery mobile?

EDIT2:
It should look like
http://www.vissit.com/projects/eventCalendar/
[image]

EDIT: 
All I really could come up with is :

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_mobile.shtml

but this seems far from compatible on multiple platforms, anyone a suggestion what else to do to get a custom event calender?

Perhaps some basic code and list view stuff with jquery mobile can generate a similar results.

EDIT3:
There seems to be this one 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/ but no good decent docs our updated files for latest JQM anywhere to be found in the jquery mobile repo or online :(

Comment: This might be better suited for http://programmer.stackexchange.com

Comment: J.T. Sage wrote a decent date picker for mobile, searching Google for "jquery mobile datepicker", it came-up as the second result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a calendar with event management options that works across iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 which goes with jQuery and jQuery Mobile as well take a look at [Mobiscroll Calendar](http://mobiscroll.com/component/calendar).